# Success ajax not working when sending Form Data on laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, form-data

So i have button that have onclick on function sendCode. Sendcode will send form data as its data. The problem is success ajax is not working. Is there any problem on my code?

Here are my Send code function

```
    const sendCode = () => {
                     // Get content
        let lang = $("#lang").val()
        let code = editor.getValue()
        let input = document.getElementById("input").value

        var codeBlob = new Blob([code], {
            type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        });

        var inputBlob = new Blob([input], {
            type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        });

        var formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('input', inputBlob)
        formData.append('code', codeBlob)
        formData.append('lang', lang)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: formData,
            url: '{{ route("pemain.contest.prg.question.runcode", ['contest' => $contest->slug, 'question' => $question->id]) }}',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(response) {
               changeOutput()
            }, 
        })
    }
```

My Change Output function are as follows

```
const changeOutput = () => {
            let username = "{{Auth::user()->team->user->username}}"
            let path = "/storage/prg/pemain/"+username+"/result.out"
            file_get_contents(path)
        }
```

Comment: What happens in route 'pemain.contest.prg.question.runcode' ? Could you add the code which returns response?

Comment: Could you add this to your ajax request and show us what the console shows? `complete: function (result) { console.log(result); }` ?